# Arrow before and after lines CSS

Tags: css

I need to create arrow before and after a line. I created the  line but im not greatly proficient in CSS. Any help would be great..

Need a small arrow on both sides of the line.

```css
.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: green;
  border-width:
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```